# Spring security: Using a custom login page: How does spring process the provided login data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was reading through some guides on how to create a custom login page in Spring security. By now I have a config class like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app",true);
    }

}
```

A simple login page (posting to `perform_login`):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form name='f' action="perform_login" method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>User:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And also I have an implementation of `UserDetailsService`, which Spring Security should use to look up users in databse:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class TMUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        TMUser user = userRepository.findById(userName).orElse(null);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
        }
        return User.builder()
                .username(user.getName())
                .password(user.getPasswordHash())
                .roles(user.getRoles().stream().map(UserRole::getName).toArray(String[]::new))
                .build();
    }

}
```

And my question is now: How exactly is the call to `.loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")` supposed to work? Should Spring automatically generate a controller at the url `/perform_login`, which would use my implementation of `UserDetailsService` (see above) to find and authorize (or not authorize) users? Or should I build such a controller by myself? I would expect, that Spring can build the controller automatically, but currently, after submitting the login form, I am (correctly) redirected to `/perform_login`, which returns a 404 error saying `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`. So, the controller does not seem to exist ... Where is my misunderstanding? If I have to build the controller by myself, then the implementation of `UserDetailsService` would become useless ...

Comment: 404 error, check whether the request url is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think it would not generate a controller with the url `/perform_login`. It just creates a matcher with the supplied pattern and HTTP method in a case insensitive manner.
You can find it out at `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer`

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance
 * @see HttpSecurity#formLogin()
 */
public FormLoginConfigurer() {
    super(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), null);
    usernameParameter("username");
    passwordParameter("password");
}


/**
 * Creates a new instance
 * @param authenticationFilter the {@link AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter} to
 * use
 * @param defaultLoginProcessingUrl the default URL to use for
 * {@link #loginProcessingUrl(String)}
 */
protected AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer(F authenticationFilter,
        String defaultLoginProcessingUrl) {
    this();
    this.authFilter = authenticationFilter;
    if (defaultLoginProcessingUrl != null) {
        loginProcessingUrl(defaultLoginProcessingUrl);
    }
}


// ~ Constructors
// ===================================================================================================

public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So it means, if I use a custom login page, there is no way, how to let Spring login users automatically (by finding them through the UserDetailsService)? Only if I use the default login page, then the UserDetailsService would be used?

Comment: Of course you can use custom login page and  UserDetailsService, just check your configuration whether right or not

Comment: But you say, that Spring does not create the controller, so I would need to create my own controller at the url /perform_login and inject the UserDetailsService there to look for users and authorize them by myself? Or is there some way to let Spring do this under the hood - while keeping the custom login page? If yes - how? The request url should be right, I think - the browser redirects to /perform_login, but there is nothing there... Sorry for many questions :)

Comment: There is a default `/login` url. If you set loginProcessingUrl with `/perform_login`, the default url would be instead of  `/perform_login`.

Comment: .login page(..) defines which page to show when auth is required.. spring security will redirect to login.jsp page

Comment: Once you submit the login page with username and password, spring security needs a clue (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) to trigger auth. So it uses loginProcessingUrl(..) to check the path. If path matches then authentication is performed